# Java XChart points text labels

Tags: java, user-interface, charts, knowm-xchart

I am trying to add text labels to data points in [xChart](http://xeiam.com/xchart/). 
But I have no any ideas how to add additional information.

```
Series sc = chrGraph.addSeries("Scale", z, y);
```

Here is the fragment of code of series data. z, y - arrays of double. I have a string array with point labels information.

Comment: There's an open issue to add this feature to XChart: https://github.com/timmolter/XChart/issues/106